# Word for "the increase of personal power or influence"

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a single word that means "the increase of personal power or influence" or "the increase of political power"?

Comment: Please explain more in what context you would like to use such a word. Give us some sentences with ? marking the missing word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [thefreedictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/aggrandisement)...

> **aggrandisement**
>    *the act of increasing the wealth or prestige or power or scope of something*

Answer (score 0):

Your description is quite open so I focused on the idea of *influence* and *fame*.

Verbs

- propagate
- elect
- entitle
- empower
- authorize

Here are more general adjectives (become .../grow more ...)

- prominent
- prestigious
- remarkable
- renowned
- captivating
- vehement
- auspicious (compared to other options)
- rallied/supported
- respected

In an evil/villanous sense:

**notorious** or
**infamous**